# Run ffmpeg without outputting configuration information?

Tags: python, logging, ffmpeg, subprocess, stderr

I'm invoking [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) with [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), and trying to capture the [`stderr`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) output and write it to [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html).

```
args = ['ffmpeg', '-i', path]
if start:
    args += ['-ss', start]
if end:
    args += ['-t', end]
args += [
    '-vcodec', 'copy',
    '-acodec', 'copy',
    '-scodec', 'copy',
    '-f', 'mpegts',
    '-y', '/dev/stdout']
self.child = subprocess.Popen(
    args,
    stdin=open(os.devnull, 'rb'),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

`ffmpeg` generates a lot of configuration information like the following:

> FFmpeg version 0.6.2-4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1,
>   Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the Libav
>   developers   built on Mar 22 2011
>   15:55:04 with gcc 4.5.2
>   configuration:
>   --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static   WARNING: library configuration
>   mismatch   libavutil   configuration:
>   --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static   libavcodec  configuration:
>   --extra-version=4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static   libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
>   libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
>   libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
>   libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>   libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
>   libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
>   libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

Prior to finally outputting the stuff I'd like to log:

> Seems stream 0 codec frame rate
>   differs from container frame rate:
>   47.95 (66893/1395) -> 23.98 (66893/2790) At least one output file
>   must be specified

Is there an option to prevent this excessive output? Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/326629/736190

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is now possible as of FFmpeg 2.2 with the [`-hide_banner`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options) option. See also the relevant [commit](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/b4c89c90ffc723c38282fbf061bf65da67e011b2) and [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3246).

Comment: Would be nice if there was an FFOPTIONS environment variable I could add this to so the banner is always hidden, but I don't think there is any such feature?

Comment: You can put `alias ffmpeg='ffmpeg -hide_banner'` in your .bashrc (or another file relevant to your shell) to keep `ffmpeg` from cluttering your terminal without having to specify the option every time

Comment: Using a bash function `function ffmpeg () { command ffmpeg -hide_banner "$@"; }; export -f ffmpeg` instead of an alias has the advantage that you can use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) directly (instead of using [env_parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html))

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no way, `loglevel` is no use. Look at ffmpeg.c:

```
init_opts();
show_banner();
```

and cmdutils.c:

```
void show_banner(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s version " FFMPEG_VERSION ", Copyright (c) %d-%d the FFmpeg developers\n",
            program_name, program_birth_year, this_year);
    fprintf(stderr, "  built on %s %s with %s %s\n",
            __DATE__, __TIME__, CC_TYPE, CC_VERSION);
    fprintf(stderr, "  configuration: " FFMPEG_CONFIGURATION "\n");
    print_all_libs_info(stderr, INDENT|SHOW_CONFIG);
    print_all_libs_info(stderr, INDENT|SHOW_VERSION);
}
```

See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-issues@lscube.org/msg08093.html) for an unsuccessful attempt of skipping it (I don't get what the GPL has to do with anything of this). I suggest you to [file a bug](http://www.ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) and hope you are convicing enough.

As many others, I have ffmpeg compiled with `show_banner()` commented out, it's simply tiresome.

Comment: Their bug tracker is epically crap. +1 if you can get a link to a bug _in the tracker_ discussing the banner. Thanks.

Comment: I'd still like to give +1 if you can link to a relevant bug in their tracker.

Comment: @Matt: I didn't find any bug report concerning the banner: https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/query?status=closed&status=new&status=open&status=reopened&max=3000&order=priority. But note that one of the authors (Ronald S. Bultje) said in the mailing-list that this was not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ffmpeg's manpage, especially the `-loglevel` parameter.

Comment: I tried -loglevel panic and it suppressed the output. https://superuser.com/questions/326629/how-can-i-make-ffmpeg-be-quieter-less-verbose

Answer (score -2):

FFmpeg != Libav

`ffmpeg` from FFmpeg with `-loglevel` parameter works as expected.

Comment: What version of ffmpeg? The accepted solution mentions this sites not in fact work.

Comment: seems like ffmpeg -loglevel <level> works for any loglevel higher than "info". The loglevel parameters are (from least verbose to most): "quiet" "panic" "fatal" "error" "warning" "info" "verbose" "debug". I'm using ffmpeg 1.0 (built on mac).